# Assigning (const char *) pointer type - Segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct

Below is the representation for `Person`,

```
typedef struct{

  const char *firstName;
  const char *lastName;
}PersonDetails;

typedef struct{

  const long *sinKey;
  PersonDetails *value;
}Person;
```

---

where, populating the `firstName` member creates segmentation fault,

```
int main(void){
  ....
  Person *person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
  const long key1 =  364222888L;
  printf("Before key assignment\n");
  person->sinKey = &key1;
  printf("Before first name assignment\n");
  person->value->firstName = "Sham";
  printf("Before last name assignment\n");
  person->value->lastName = "S";
  ....
}
```

---

`const char *firstName` holds an immutable string. This immutable string gets stored in `.rodata` section. `firstname` can change its pointing location.

---

But, below is the output,

```
$ ./pq.exe
...
Before key assignment
Before first name assignment
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: `value` is not allocated...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do

```
Person *person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
```

you only allocate memory for the `person` structure. You do not allocate memory for `person->value`. You don't even *initialize* `person->value` so its value will be *indeterminate*, leading to *undefined behavior* when you dereference it.

My recommendation is to *not* use a pointer for `person->value`, just a plain structure (non-pointer) instance.

---

On an unrelated note, be careful with that pointer `person->sinKey`, especially if you in your actual code create the structure in another function. The assignment you make will make `person->sinKey` to point to the local variable, which will go out of scope once the function returns.

It works if you create the structure in the `main` function since then the lifetime of the variable you make `person->sinKey` point to will be the lifetime of the program.

This, together with the above problem, leads me to wonder why you use pointers so much? Pointers are the main cause for problems in code, especially for (relative) beginners.

Comment: Do you mean, `PersonDetails value` member? where `PersonDetails` as shown above?

Comment: @overexchange Yes exactly.

Comment: Am wrong. There is no value add by maintaining `*sinKey`

Comment: @overexchange What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: @RoadRunner I generally write data structures using vtable approach. [Here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/blob/master/design2Code/pqClient.c) is one, working after code changes. Go thru [ReadMe](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/blob/master/design2Code/ReadMe.txt) for instructions

Answer (score 2):

You must add allocation for `value` member

```
person->value = malloc (sizeof(PersonDetails));
```

And you must check `malloc` return values, always

```
if (person->value != NULL)
{
   // YOUR STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Person *person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
```

is not sufficient.

You have to allocate memory for person->value as well.

```
Person *person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
person->value = malloc(sizeof(PersonDetails));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use `PersonDetails *value`, you need to allocate some space for this with `malloc()`. Otherwise its just a dangling pointer not pointing anywhere.

As @Some programmer dude suggested, you can simply use `PersonDetails value`, and then you don't need any allocation, as its not longer a pointer.

If you decide to use this approach, your code would then look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    const char *firstName;
    const char *lastName;
}PersonDetails;

typedef struct{
    const long *sinKey;
    PersonDetails value;
}Person;


int main(void) {
    Person *person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    const long key1 =  364222888L;

    person->sinKey = &key1;
    printf("%ld\n", *(person->sinKey));

    person->value.firstName = "Bob";
    printf("%s\n", person->value.firstName);

    person->value.lastName = "Smith";
    printf("%s\n", person->value.lastName);

    return 0;
}
```

I am still unsure why you use `const long *sinKey;`? Does this really need to be a pointer?